# How to merge 3 different image views into single uiimage in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

In my app i'm having three different image views that three image views should be merged into single uiimage.
first imageview for picking images from gallery/camera
second imageview for frame images 
third imageview for Overlay images(these are placed on the first image view.my issue! is while sharing i need to merge those three into single uiimage 
while running it is only showing second image and third merging the first image is not viewing.please answer me if any one know the issue .Thanks in advance
Here is my sharing code please help me .

```
[self.OverLayImgView setAlpha:0.6]; UIImage *FirstImage = ImgView.image;
UIImage *ScndImage=self.FramesAppliedImg.image;
UIImage *ThirdImg=self.OverLayImgView.image;
CGSize firstImagSize=[FirstImage size];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(firstImagSize);
[FirstImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(20,20,315,315)];
[ScndImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,355,355)];
[ThirdImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(20, 20, 315,315)];
UIImage *newImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Update your question with the code.

Comment: Please suggest me if anyone knows the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Some view class just using UIView instead of:

```
- (UIImage *)stitchedImageWithSize:(CGSize)size
                  borderOffset:(CGFloat)borderOffset
                   borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor
{

    UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, size.width, size.height)];
    v.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
    v.image = self.image;
    v.contentMode = self.contentMode;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < self.subviews.count; i++) {
    id obj = self.self.subviews[i];

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[V_freeStitchingCell class]]) {
        V_freeStitchingCell *cell = obj;

        CGRect rect = cell.rect_first;

        //make rect with center
        rect.origin.x = cell.center.x - (rect.size.width / 2.f);
        rect.origin.y = cell.center.y - (rect.size.height / 2.f);

        //make rect with scale
        rect.size.width = rect.size.width * size.width / self.frame.size.width;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.height * size.height / self.frame.size.height;
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x * size.width / self.frame.size.width;
        rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y * size.height / self.frame.size.height;

        if (cell.pImg_value) {
            UIView *sv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
            sv.backgroundColor = borderColor;

            CGSize tmpsize = cell.frame.size;
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithImage:cell.pImg_value inRect:CGRectZero size:&tmpsize errMsg:nil];
            UIImageView *vimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(borderOffset, borderOffset, rect.size.width - (borderOffset * 2), rect.size.height - (borderOffset * 2))];
            vimg.image = img;
            [sv addSubview:vimg];

            [v addSubview:sv];
            sv.transform = cell.transform;
        }
    }
}

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef contxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [v.layer renderInContext:contxt];
    UIImage *des = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return des;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response if adding image to subview i am getting exception